# Map a collection of objects to a single object that summarizes the collection

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, lodash

### Context

I have this code:

```
  fspMap = _(cart.items)
    .filter( (r) -> r._id )
    .filter( (r) -> r.style.premium? )
    .groupBy( (r) -> r.style.premium.code )
    .value()
  console.log fspMap
```

where cart.items is:

```
[ { _id: 'SA01-MBL0',
    style: 
     { __v: 4,
       _id: 'SA01',
       name: [Object] },
    quantity: 12,
    weight: 165 },
  { _id: 'EP01-BB1',
    quantity: 3,
    style: 
     { __v: 14,
       _id: 'EP01',
       premium: [Object],
       name: [Object] },
    weight: 155 },
  { _id: 'EP02-BL0',
    style: 
     { __v: 5,
       _id: 'EP02',
       premium: [Object],
       name: [Object] },
    quantity: 1,
    weight: 145 },
  { _id: 'EP02-BR0',
    style: 
     { __v: 5,
       _id: 'EP02',
       premium: [Object],
       name: [Object] },
    quantity: 1,
    weight: 145 } ]
```

### Problem

I am trying to get a new array grouped by style.premium.code, this is what i get when i run the above code:

```
{ FSP01: [ { _id: 'EP01-BB1', quantity: 3, style: [Object], weight: 155 } ],
  FSP02: 
   [ { _id: 'EP02-BL0', style: [Object], quantity: 1, weight: 145 },
     { _id: 'EP02-BR0', style: [Object], quantity: 1, weight: 145 } ] }
```

but what i want to get is to the quantities and weights for each value to get something like:

```
{ 
  FSP01: { quantity: 3, weight: 155 },
  FSP02:{ quantity: 2, weight: 290 },
}
```

any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an array of items `[item, item]`

1) reduce the array to an object with `_.reduce(arr, function() {}, {})`, since you need your object to only have quantity and weight

```
_.reduce(arr, function(result, item) {
}, {quantity: 0, weight: 0})
```

2) the body of the function should take each item and grab the quantity and weight and add it to the initial value

```
_.reduce(items, function(result, item) {
  _.forIn(result, function (value, key) {
    result[key] += item[key]
  })
  return result
}, {quantity: 0, weight: 0})
```

3) finally do this for each group, since your group is an object which maps codes to an array of items you can use `_.mapValues`

```
_.mapValues(groups, function (items) {
  return _.reduce(items, function(result, item) {
    _.forIn(result, function (value, key) {
      result[key] += item[key]
    })
    return result
  }, {quantity: 0, weight: 0})
})
```

Final solution

```js
var groups = { FSP01: [ { _id: 'EP01-BB1', quantity: 3, style: [Object], weight: 155 } ],
  FSP02: 
   [ { _id: 'EP02-BL0', style: [Object], quantity: 1, weight: 145 },
     { _id: 'EP02-BR0', style: [Object], quantity: 1, weight: 145 } ] }


var g = _(groups)
  .mapValues(function (items) {
    return _.reduce(items, function (result, item) {
      _.forIn(result, function (value, key) {
        result[key] += item[key]
      })
      return result
    }, {quantity: 0, weight: 0})
  })
  .value()

document.write(JSON.stringify(g))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.11.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your lodash chain into something like this:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ejevtjjf/)**

```
var result = _(data)
  .filter('_id') // only items with _id property
  .filter('style.premium') // only items with style.premium object
  .groupBy('style.premium.code') // group by style.premium.code
  .mapValues((item) => ({ // map each object item
    quantity: _.sumBy(item, 'quantity'), // sum of quantity
    weight: _.sumBy(item, 'weight') // sum weight
  }))
  .value();
```